# Can't install python 2.7.7 locally - OS version gets installed instead

Tags: ubuntu, installation, python

I have a Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS virtual machine (x86) with Python 2.7.3 as OS version.

I'm trying to compile and install to a local path Python 2.7.7, which I need for some fixes related to a project.

Configure and compilation goes through fine, but it doesn't install the version I compiled.

```
~/src/Python-2.7.7$ ./configure --prefix /home/dev/.localpython --enable-shared
~/src/Python-2.7.7$ make
~/src/Python-2.7.7$ make install


/home/dev/.localpython/bin/python2.7 -V
Python 2.7.3
```

Any idea on what could cause this behavior?

Thanks

PS: I need --enabled-shared for another compilation

Comment: By default `python` should be installed to `/usr/bin/python/` but definitely will not into `/home/dev/.localpython/bin/python2.7`. In order to install in custom location, you need to set this location explicitly

Comment: @user1700494 I'm setting the location with the --prefix param. I need to run multiple versions of python for different virtual environments. This works fine on other machines, just not on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to install it using `pyenv`  https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv. I've followed the install instructions from the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv.git ~/.pyenv
echo 'export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(pyenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL
pyenv install 2.7.7
```